# Elegant way to copy and paste grouped lines of text into another file

Tags: text, command-line, sed, copy-paste

Assume I have two files. How can I execute the following operation, i.e. copy a tagged part from one file into a certain location of another? Would some `sed` command do the job? What is the most practical way?

**File #1:**

```
This paragraph does not belong to the poem.

{ begin passage #1 }

When from a place he run away,
He never at the place did stay;
And while he run, as I am told,
He never stood still for young or old.

He often squeaked, and sometimes violent,
And when he squeaked he never was silent.
Though never instructed by a cat,
He knew a mouse was not a rat.

{ end passage #1 }

This as well does not.
```

**File #2:**

```
There was a little guinea pig,
Who being little, was not big;
He always walked upon his feet,
And never fasted when he eat.

{ input passage #1 file #1 }

One day, as I am certified,
He took a whim, and fairly died;
And as I am told by men of sense,
He never has been living since.
```

I would like to have the passage from file #1 inserted into file #2 at the given mark. Help and ideas are both appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking to have various values for `passage #1 (file #1)`, or is a hardcoded solution acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked "What is the most practical way", I'm responding w a mixture of `sed` and `awk` using shell scripting to glue the whole thing together.

Trying to solve this only with `sed` might be possible, but not worth the time to figure it out.

There are almost certainly further optimizations that could be made, but I've tried to write code that you can understand, rather than a one-liner ;-) .

```
#!/bin/ksh

sed -n '/^{ begin passage/,/^{ end passage /p' file_1 | sed '/^{/d' > /tmp/$$.segment

awk -v segFile="/tmp/$$.segment" '{
  if ($0 ~ /^{ input passage/) {
    while (getline < segFile > 0 ) {
      print $0
    }
  next
  }
  else {
    print $0
  }
}'  file_2

rm /tmp/$$.segment
```

**output**

```
There was a little guinea pig,
Who being little, was not big;
He always walked upon his feet,
And never fasted when he eat.


When from a place he run away,
He never at the place did stay;
And while he run, as I am told,
He never stood still for young or old.

He often squeaked, and sometimes violent,
And when he squeaked he never was silent.
Though never instructed by a cat,
He knew a mouse was not a rat.


One day, as I am certified,
He took a whim, and fairly died;
And as I am told by men of sense,
He never has been living since.
```

You can change `#!/bin/ksh` to `#!/bin/bash` if needed.

You could post-filter your output to eliminate duplicate blank lines, but its not clear what your ultimate need is.

IHTH

Comment: I would not have been able to come up with *that* sed/awk script ... nice, learned something new again! :)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/{ begin/,/{ end/!b;//!p' file1 | sed -e '/{ input/r /dev/stdin' -e '//d' file2
```

Filter the lines from file1 and insert them into file2. The stdout from the first sed command becomes the stdin file for the second sed command. Two sed commands are needed in the second sed invocation because the `r` command must be ended with a newline (or a new `-e` sed command). The second sed command deletes the line where the lines from the first file are inserted.

Comment: less is more! Good alternate, and for some, the golden 1-liner ;-) Good luck to all.